# Paginación API RESTFull + Node.js + Express + Mongoose

Tags: nodejs, express, mongoose, restful

Ahora mismo tengo algo como esto:

```
function getBooks(req, res) {
  var perPage = req.query.perPage;
  var page = req.query.page;

  Book.find({})
      .skip((page - 1) * perPage)
      .limit(perPage)
      .exec((err, books) => {
          if (err) {
            res.status.(500).send({message: "Error en la petición"});
          } else {
            res.set('X-limit', perPage);
            res.set('X-page', page);

            res.status(200).send({books});
          }
      });
}
```

Necesito pasar también el total de documentos de la base de datos books para la paginación, algo como:

```
var total = Book.count()
res.set('X-total', total);
```

El problema es que count() es asíncrono. Entonces no sé como plantearlo.

Comment: Puedes usar `Promise` o `async/await`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes utilizar Promesas ([`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Promise))

Quedando de esta forma:

```
function getBooks(req, res) {
    var perPage = req.query.perPage;
    var page = req.query.page;
    var booksResult = null;

    Book.find({})
        .skip((page - 1) * perPage)
        .limit(perPage)
        .exec()
        .then((books) => {
            res.set('X-limit', perPage);
            res.set('X-page', page);
            booksResult = books;
            return Book.count(); 
        })
        .then((total) => {
            res.set('X-total', total);
            res.status(200).send({ booksResult });
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            res.status(500).send({ message: "Error en la petición" });
        });
}
```

o bien [`async/await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/funcion_asincrona)
(Esta característica solo esta disponible a partir de node 7.6.0)

Quedando igual de la siguiente forma:

```
async function getBooks(req, res) {
    var perPage = req.query.perPage;
    var page = req.query.page;

    try {
        var books = await Book.find({})
                              .skip((page - 1) * perPage)
                              .limit(perPage)
                              .exec();
        var total = await Book.count();
        res.set('X-limit', perPage);
        res.set('X-page', page);
        res.set('X-total', total);
        res.status(200).send({ books });
    } catch(err) {
        res.status(500).send({ message: "Error en la petición" });
    }
}
```